# I can't find an example of pyautogui.locateOnWindow

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to locate the cordinates of an image with locateOnWindow()

```
position = pt.locateOnWindow(image, 'Discord', grayscale=True, confidence=.9)
```

I get this error and the discord window icon turns into orange. [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9brpF.png)

> raise PyGetWindowException('Error code from Windows: %s - %s' % (errorCode, _formatMessage(errorCode)))
> pygetwindow.PyGetWindowException: Error code from Windows: 0 - The operation completed successfully.

Comment: Hi. I also have the same problem. Did you find any solution to focus on a specific program/window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `pyautogui` documentation, as [Screenshot Functions](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) says: you can call the `locateOnScreen()` function to get the screen coordinates. The return value is a 4-integer tuple: (left, top, width, height). This tuple can be passed to `center()` function to get the `X` and `Y` coordinates at the center of this region.

So I saved a discord icon image from my laptop and found the coordinates correctly as below:

Image:

[image: Discord]

```
import pyautogui

image = 'discord.png'

locate = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image, grayscale=True, confidence=0.8)

position = pyautogui.center(pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image, grayscale=True, confidence=0.8))
```

If you `print(locate)`:

```
Box(left=91, top=288, width=23, height=26)
```

If you `print(position)`:

```
Point(x=102, y=301)
```

Comment: genius,  solve my problem~

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After searching through the documentation I found this on their [roadmap](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/roadmap.html):

- Click coordinates relative to a window, instead of the entire screen.

Since the function 'locateOnWindow' also does not get commented on in the documentation, and I found no examples nor solutions - just as OP - I wonder whether this feature is simply not yet implemented even though the command is there.

**Alternate solution:** While not exactly the answer you wished for, try another module such as [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contents.html) that allows for control of windows and use it to put your window in the foreground in a reproductible way (same position and size).

***Edit:*** you can use *pyautogui* for that...

```
active_window = pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle('title')[0]
active_window.activate()
active_window.maximize()
```